# Get load at a moment in time or getloadavg() for a smaller time period in Python in Linux (CentOS)

Tags: python, linux, load

Currently, am using Python's `os.getloadavg()` to get an idea of the current load on the server `(Centos 6.3)`

According to the python documentation, `os.getloadavg()` "Returns the number of processes in the system run queue averaged over the last 1, 5, and 15 minutes" :

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getloadavg

```
os.getloadavg()
Return the number of processes in the system run queue averaged over the last 1, 5, and 15 minutes or raises OSError if the load average was unobtainable.
```

**Question:**

- Is it possible to get the number of processes in the system run queue
  at the current instant?
- If not, is it possible to get the average over a shorter period of
  time, like the last 5 or 10 seconds?

The reason I am asking is because I am getting the load average, then if it is too high, am killing some processes. This can potentially happen many times per minute, so am concerned too many processes will be killed before the 1 minute average catches up.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the 1 minute average a sliding-window or run every minute ? If it is a sliding window you can apply difference to it after an initial wait time of 1 minute, and that will give you an estimate of the new tasks every n-seconds you choose to check the load.

Comment: As far as I know, those averages are maintained by the kernel(at least in linux). So you probably can't get averages for shorter time durations. However, it should be possible to get the current number of running processes. But that will not necessarily be equal to the number of processes in the system run queue which has a very technically precise definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.5/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt#L1207) in the Linux 3.5 kernel source, you can retrieve the number of currently running processes from `/proc/stat`:

```
>>> for l in open("/proc/stat"):
...   l = l.split()
...   if l[0] == 'procs_running':
...     result = int(l[1])
... 
>>> print result
6
>>>
```

The same number is available in `/proc/loadavg`:

```
>>> print int(open("/proc/loadavg").next().split()[3].split('/')[0])
6
```